# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() error: System.UnathorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, exception, authorization

Please, help me! I have a problem.
Code:

```
...    
currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(absoluteCurrentPath);
FileInfo[] allFiles = currentDirectory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
model.AllFiles = new List<MyFile>();
foreach (var f in allFiles)
{

    model.AllFiles.Add(new MyFile(f.Name, f.FullName, Utilites.ConvertBytesToMegabytes(f.Length)));
}
```

When `DirectoryInfo CurrentDirectory = "C:\\"` or equals other directory with system files, then except error: System.UnathorizedAccessException.
When I take in a block try-catch, it only skips `GetFiles()`.
How Can I get all files and skip only system files or get all files without skiping files?
Thanks!

Comment: which window are you running your project? I saw that you dont have permission to access directly `C` disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a method that I wrote some times ago:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern = null)
{
    searchPattern = searchPattern ?? "*";

    var queue = new Queue<string>();

    queue.Enqueue(path);

    do
    {
        path = queue.Dequeue();

        foreach (var file in SafeEnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern))
        {
            yield return new FileInfo(file);
        }

        foreach (var directory in SafeEnumerateDirectories(path))
        {
            queue.Enqueue(directory);
        }
    }
    while (queue.Any());
}

static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }
    catch (SecurityException) { }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}

static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateDirectories(string path)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }
    catch (SecurityException) { }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

The method skips folder you don't have permission.

Comment: You mean, skips the folders you don't have permission or a security issue occurs and swallows the exception.
I personally do not like the idea of just swallowing exceptions.

Comment: With IO it's something you have to accept, take a look a [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: I edited the answer, so that the method returns `FileInfo` instead.

Comment: It works, but only when path directory "C:\\" there was a new exception "System.IO.PathTooLongException" in line:
                    yield return new FileInfo(file);

Comment: You have to handle it. You can catch it and skip those files, or check for Length of path and avoid exception.

Comment: Thank you, Alessandro D'Andria.